# lighttpd version error, indexfile

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I am trying to use lighttpd, and installed it on a switch. However trying to run it gives this error:

```
2013-03-15 15:29:49: (plugin.c.417) plugin-version doesn't match lighttpd-version for indexfile 
2013-03-15 15:29:49: (server.c.890) Initialization of plugins failed. Going down.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It indicates version of installed lighttpd is different from the version of code, which you are using. 
Check installed version on machine and then check SConstruct version.
Both should same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hook a mod_*.so file from somewhere else into this server? Lighttpd hooks modules mentioned in module.conf file. It checks for the lighttpd version with which the module was compiled with. Comment out all the modules in the conf file. Then try to start again. You can see which module is causing the problem by adding them one by one.